# How to use ng-messages with such a input like <input name='user[name]'>

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am new to Angular, and try to use ng-messages to do something like form-validate. Now, I have no problem when I use ng-message in the following situation:

```
<form name='loginForm' novalidate>
    <input name='user' required>
    <div ng-messages=loginForm.user.$error>
        <div ng-message='required'> this field is required...</div>
    </div>
<form>
```

but when I change name attribute of input,`<input name='user[name]' required>`, ng-message would not work again. Is there anyone can help me?

Comment: I don't think angular allows for populating name attribute dynamically. See ng-form to resolve this in documentation https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngForm

Answer (score 0):

Form name attributes **CAN** be populated dynamically.
Remember, `name` attribute reads a string, and `ng-messages` reads an angular expression that should be evaluated to a reference to the `$error` object.

Since this reference is obtained through an angular expression, it can even be a method that returns the reference.

In your case, assuming your name attribute  looks like this:

```
<form name="loginForm">
    <input name="{{ user.name }}" required />
</form>
```

The correct syntax should be:

```
<div ng-messages="loginForm[user.name].$error" ></ div>
```